# Precison issue with sigmoid activation function for Tensorflow/Keras 2.3.1

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Assuming the following forward pass in a classic ANN
(Based on https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/):

> [image: net_{h1} = w_1 * i_1 + w_2 * i_2 + b_1 * 1]

> [image: net_{h1} = 0.15 * 0.05 + 0.2 * 0.1 + 0.35 * 1 = 0.3775]

Now let's use a sigmoid activation on that, I get:

> [image: out_{h1} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-net_{h1}}} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-0.3775}} = 0.593269992]

So far so good, now let's check the result of this calculation in python:

```
1 / (1+ math.exp(-0.3775)) # ... = 0.5932699921071872, OK
```

However this is double precision and since Keras uses float32 let's calculate the same thing but with float32, I get:

```
w1 = np.array(0.15, dtype=np.float32)
i1 = np.array(0.05, dtype=np.float32)
w2 = np.array(0.2, dtype=np.float32)
i2 = np.array(0.1, dtype=np.float32)
b1 = np.array(0.35, dtype=np.float32)
k1 = np.array(1, dtype=np.float32)
k2= np.array(1, dtype=np.float32)

n1 = w1 * i1 + w2 * i2 + b1 * k1
np.array(k2 / (1 + np.exp(-n1)), dtype=np.float32) # --->array(0.59327, dtype=float32)
```

Ok so normally I should be able to get 0.59327 for our ***out_{h1}*** using Keras float32 framework.

Let's now try to get this result using Keras:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np


model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))                    # Build only one layer (enough for example)
model.compile(optimizer = SGD(lr = 0.5),loss='mse')         # Don't really care for this example, simply for compilation
input = np.array([[0.05, 0.10]])                            # Set input, same as the ones provided in the example
output = np.array([[0.01, 0.99]])                           # Don't really care for this example since we want to check activation only



weights = [np.array([[0.15,  0.20 ],                        # Required for set_weights
        [0.25,  0.30]], dtype=np.float32),
 np.array([0.35,  0.35], dtype=np.float32)]
model.build(input.shape)                                    # Required for set_weights
model.set_weights(weights)                                  # Set the weights to be the same as the one provided in the example


model.predict(np.array([[0.05, 0.10]], dtype=np.float32))   # This can be seen as out_{h1}
                                                            # array([[0.5944759 , 0.59628266]], dtype=float32)
                                                            # NOK: 0.5944759 != 0.59327
```

Can someone explain to me why I get 0.5944759 instead of 0.59327? The result seem far from the expected ouput and if possible provide an example of calculation and/or a way to get the expected output of 0.59327.

Please note this example was done using:

- tensorflow                2.3.1
- numpy                     1.18.5
- python                    3.8.12

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow perform the Dense layer row to column:
It multiplies each row of your input with a column in the weights matrix, You need to transpose your weights matrix, if you do it you will get the correct result.

I validated using your code just modified:

```
weights = [np.array([[0.15, 0.20],  # Required for set_weights
                     [0.2, 0.30]], dtype=np.float32),
           np.array([0.35, 0.35], dtype=np.float32)]
```

To (pay attention to the transpose operator **T**:

```
weights = [np.array([[0.15, 0.20],  # Required for set_weights
                     [0.2, 0.30]], dtype=np.float32).T,
           np.array([0.35, 0.35], dtype=np.float32)]
```

Comment: Wow, such a short and sweet answer for my question. Thx!